# Button with Image, Why does button command not fire when image is clicked?

Tags: wpf

The button command only fires if the mouse is not over the image when it is clicked. What am I missing?

```
<Button Cursor="Hand" Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}">
    <Image Source="image.png" />                         
</Button>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think your image is swallowing your mouse clicks.

Try adding IsHitTestVisible="False" to your image.